# If I call the same postgres function with the same arguments twice in a query, does it calculate once or twice?

Tags: postgresql, performance

If I make the following query in postgres, is it calculating the ts_rank twice or just once? If it is calculating it twice, is it possible to make it calculate it only once?

```
SELECT id, name, "createdAt", price, ts_rank(document, to_tsquery(:query)) AS rank
FROM search_index
WHERE document @@ to_tsquery(:query)
ORDER BY ts_rank(document, to_tsquery(:query)) DESC;
```

Comment: Depends on whether the function is marked as immutable, stable, or volatile, and what the predicted cost is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it should be calculated only once time. Postgres detects equal expressions. Generally, if you afraid about this, then you can calculate expression in subquery.

Some like:

```
SELECT c1, c1 FROM (SELECT exp AS c1) s;
```

The function `to_tsquery()` is very expensive without [fulltext index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX). if you have fulltext index, and if there are only one hundreds selected records, then overhead of `ts_rank` should not be significant.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I have set up a fulltext index using `CREATE INDEX idx_fts_search ON search_index USING gin(document);`.